# Set Tab Order in ASP.Net GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that's displaying a bunch of name/value combinations.  The name column is a hyperlink to a details page.  The value column is editable - it displays its text in a `<asp:TextBox>`.  I'd like to set up the tab order so that the user can press tab once to go to the next value textbox.  Currently, pressing tab takes the focus to the hyperlink on the next row rather than value box.  I'd like the hyperlink to be "skipped" and focus to jump directly to the second column (the value column) in the next row.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there something that prevents you from using the [Control.TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tabindex.aspx) property? I'm guessing that your hyperlinks are normal HTML, but the documentation implies that this will work using ASP HyperLink controls.

Comment: The controls are in a GridView with a variable number of rows.  I was wondering if there was a way to set up tabbing as a property of the GridView.  I guess there isn't.